# CoreData vs Archiving?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I ask this question not for a tutorial, but simply for advice. I am new to iOS programming and have made only a simple game. I want to extend the functionally of this game by including permanent character slots, who each have inventories, professions, stats, and names. For saving these locally, I need to know which route would be easier to take. So I will be saving strings, integers, and objects from probably 4 or 5 custom classes. 
Would it be possible to use NSCoding, which is supposedly easier to learn and implement? Or should I start learning CoreData?
Just a quick response as to which one you believe would work for my application would be incredible, and I really appreciate you taking a few seconds to do so.
Thank you kindly!

Comment: I'd recommend CoreData. It's not that complicated and probably more flexible for this and future projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the shortest path, NSCoding is simple.  If you want to *learn* then pick up Core Data.

Core Data is not that difficult to get the basic concepts in place.  Once you start using it you will most likely use it on every project in the future.  It really is a *core* feature of iOS.  There is almost no application in the App Store that would not benefit from what Core Data does.

Comment: Making my job hard... Haha thanks so much though, I've found a few tutorials and am excited to get started!

Comment: I hear there is even a book or two on the subject ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If your the kind of person that loves to learn new tech just for the thrill of the challenge. Then by all means go for CoreData. But it's totally overkill for this purpose. You could bang out a totally acceptable NSCoding solution to write out save files to your NSDocumentsDirectory in like an hour. Just formulate a class to use as a "Save file" with all the needed data. Then implement the NSCoding protocol in that class, and write the data to file. There's loads of tutorials on each of these steps.

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel like I should always challenge myself so CoreData it is!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to work with CoreData because you have to look to the future if you extend your game or made a lot of saving. CoreData is very efficient, fast and simplify any query you want.

Also I think its very easy to link your data of coreData to iClound

There are a lot of tutorials for CoreData like [RayWenderlich Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)